# Переменные с типом интерфеса

Tags: java, интерфейс

Создаю интерфейс:

```
static interface A {
   void Click(long id);
}
```

Я не могу понять какими свойствами будет обладать переменная, если ее инициализировать таким образом:

```
private A listener;
```

Что при такой инициализации происходит с переменной?
Какими данными или свойствами заполняется переменная?

Comment: Все объекты хранятся по ссылке. То есть в переменной будет ссылка на объект. Да же если вы поменяете тип переменной, на ссылку это ни как не повлияет. Тип нужен компилятору, что бы проверить соответствие типов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интерфейсная переменная это как бы ссылка на объект скажем так под определенным углом.

Допустим есть объект типа `Стол`, у него есть методы `сидеть за столом`, `обедать за столом`, `разобрать стол`, `собрать стол`.

Есть теперь интерфейс типа `Мебель`, у него 2 метода: `разобрать мебель` и `собрать мебель`.

Теперь, если объект типа `Стол` присвоите к переменной типа `Мебель`, то вы с переменной `Мебель` не сможете `сесть пообедать`, а сможете только `собрать` и `разобрать`.

Преимуществом такого подхода является, что вы точно также можете поступить со `Стулом`, `Диваном` и `Шкафом` и сможете хранить/работать с множеством `шкафов`, `столов` и проч. мути как с `Мебелью` - например хотя бы так:

```
ArrayList<Мебель> мебель;
```

Вместо того, чтобы писать:

```
ArrayList<Стол> столы;
ArrayList<Стул> стулья;
ArrayList<Шкаф> шкафы;
```

Как бы удобно...

Answer (score 1):

Никакими, кроме тех, что описаны в интерфейсе. Т.е. у такого объекта можно дернуть только метод Click(long id) и все. Все остальное, какие бы поля и методы там в реальном объекте не существовали - вас не касается, в этом и смысл абстрактных интерфейсов - не думать о реализации.

Comment: реализацию интерфейсов я понимаю. я не понимаю то что в этой переменной хранится. только тип или метод тоже. и вообще для чего создавать переменную такого типа.

Comment: я скорей всего задал один и тот же вопрос два раза. но не будет ли вам трудно показать допустим самую примитивную реализацию этой переменной?